# Read html's data attribute using vanilla js

Tags: javascript, html

why can't I get the value of the data-price attribute?

I want to get the data-price value, make conversions, and add it to the html markup
I know how to do it in jquery, but not in js

JS code:

```
let btn = document.getElementById('btn');
let counter = document.getElementById('counter');

btn.addEventListener("click", function () {
    btn.getAttribute('data-price');
    counter.innerHTML = btn;
    console.log(btn);
});
```

HTML code:

```
<div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
    <img src="img/img3.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
    <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
        <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
        <div  id="price" class="card__price">2499р</div>
        <a href="#" id="btn" data-price="2499" class="btn btn-primary">В корзину</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Console:

```
<a href="#" id="btn" data-price="2499" class="btn btn-primary">В корзину</a>
```

Comment: It seems that you wanted to assign the value of the attribute before using it. Something like `const price = btn.getAttribute('data-price');`

Answer (score 2):

`btn` is the element, not the value of the attribute.

You need to assign the result of `getAttribute` to a variable and use that in the `innerHTML`.

```
btn.addEventListener("click", function () {
    var btnValue = btn.getAttribute('data-price');
    counter.innerHTML = btnValue;
    console.log(btnValue);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

> You can also use `dataset` property, can be access like this `btn.dataset.price`

**Example**

```js
function myFunction(btn) {
  console.log(btn.dataset.price)
}
```

```html
  <button onclick="myFunction(this)" data-price="1200">My Button</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

[`getAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute) returns the actual `data-price` attribute value.

```
let attribute = element.getAttribute(attributeName);
```

where

- `attribute` is a string containing the value of `attributeName`.
- `attributeName` is the name of the attribute whose value you want to get.

You need to the set `counter.innerHTML` to that value like:

```
const price = btn.getAttribute('data-price');
counter.innerHTML = price;
console.log(price);
```